# WinForms how can I store value in string array (Properties.Settings.Default)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I want to store some values into my settings variables, I did some come but it seems not to work.

```
bool saveLevelSettings()
        {
            if (rightPanel.Controls.Count > 3)
            {
                for (int i = 4; i <= rightPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        switch (j)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Levels[i - 4] = rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Sblinds[i - 4] = rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Bblinds[i - 4] = rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Antes[i - 4] = rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Timers[i - 4] = rightPanel.Controls[i - 1].Controls[j].Text;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

When I try, this error throws :

[image: error]

Here are my variables :

[image: variables]

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: You might build it first into an array and assign it to the settings variable. It seems that die array is not initialized.

Comment: Use the `StringCollection` instead of the sting array, and make sure its not `null` before adding new string items to it, otherwise `new` it first.

Comment: Most welcome mate. Good day.